# Lock write to database during maintenance wordpress mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm doing a manual WordPress update.

I backed up the database to a `.sql` file.

Is there any way to prevent write to database temporarily while still allowing read to the whole MySQL database?
This is to ensure

- The backed up database is up to date
- Users are still able to browse contents on my website without disruption (I will put up a maintenance notice that your posts will not be saved etc.)

Update
The upgrading activity is only used as an example here.
I'm planning to make some changes directly to the database as well and it will take a while.

I'm sure I have seen websites (famous one) showing that they were under maintenance and that my comments/ posts would not be recorded (no write) but I was still able to browse their websites (read is ok).
I thought it was quite a reasonable need, was it not?

I'm sure there must be a way to

- Serve the caches of webpages (server-side) to users while not connecting the the database at all in up to a couple of hours (logging in/ registration will not available to users but that's ok)? How do you think I can achieve that then?

Answer (score 0):

To lock out any visitors from posting comments and such, you can go into phpmyadmin, find the wordpress user account (DB_USER as defined in wp-config.php) and revoke its insert, edit and update privileges. But this will probably not degrade gracefully into user friendly error messages when they still try anyways ignoring your messages. And if you are doing an update through php script in the way the wordpress installs itself it may still need these privledges to make any necessary modifications like adding options to the options table.

What version are you upgrading from and to? I know the install took me all of 30 seconds, and I can't imagine there would be a huge change in database between updates. But then again WP can be highly customized and I don't know the extent your site deviates from the standard install.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm about to go to sleep so I won't go into depth but one way that works for sure is if you have two MySQL users, 1 for your website to read/write from and another to do your maintenance. Your first user, you can change his privileges temporarily to read only and that should work.